# How many TF2 servers would this VPS be able to run?

Tags: gaming, server

I've been renting from a certain company for a while now, and I'm currently thinking of switching to NFOServers because I would get a cheaper deal since I plan to expand the servers further.

However it's not going to be many servers, so I was wondering if it would be possible to at least get 3 servers running on NFOServers' "Two Core VPS" plan?

Specs (If you're too lazy to open their site):

```
Two full, dedicated HT CPU cores (Nehalem or better)
2048 MB of RAM
200 GB of RAID-protected storage
8000 GB of bandwidth transfer
```

If not, how many servers will I be able to have?

Comment: Are you running any plugins? What game mode are you hosting? An MvM server takes a different amount of RAM than others.

Answer (score 4):

A Team Fortress 2 server uses about 500MB of ram for a 24 person server, with SourceMod and a few basic plugins running. The storage space you have is more than sufficient for 3 servers, as long as you aren't loading a ton of giant, uncompressed maps. The 8000GB of bandwidth will be fine for 3 servers. (I've run 14 servers on a 10000GB line, with a fast download server and never gotten close to 8000GB in a month). Compress your maps. You'll keep your bandwidth usage down and your players happy - downloading a 10 MB map is much faster than a 70 MB map.

The problem you may have is that you only have 2 cores. If you are running vanilla servers, you'll be fine. If you are running heavily modified game modes, you may experience issues.

It's also worth noting that MvM is very processor intensive. If you are running a MvM server, you will not be able to run 3 servers with only two cores.

---

I'd recommend the package you are considering, provided that:

- You are not running an MvM server
- You are not running a mod like dodgeball and a lot of projectiles. A single or double projectile game should be fine
- You know how to compress that maps to save bandwidth

Comment: Should take into account the OS usage, although that won't be much.